# Function that takes in a real number and outputs a function with it as a parameter

Tags: r, functional-programming

I want to code a function that takes in a number and returns a function with that number as a parameter. I want to later find the roots of this function it outputs.

```
fooToOptimze <- function(PD) {

  f <- function(C, k) { 0.089 * exp(1.6234 * PD) - C * exp(k * PD)}

  return(f)

}
```

However, this way, I get:

```
fooToOptimize(.5)

OUTPUT 

function(C, k) { 0.089 * exp(1.6234 * PD) - C * exp(k * PD)}
```

How should I approach this?

Comment: This solved it
```
optimer <- function(PD) {
  
  
  f <- function(C, k, p) { 0.02525947 * exp(3.439922 * p) - C * exp(k * p)}
  flinha <- purrr::partial(f, p = PD) 
  
  
  return(flinha)
   
}
```

Comment: It looks like a function is being returned exactly like you want. You can call that new function like `fooToOptimze(.5)(4, 1)`. I'm not sure exactly where you are getting stuck. Where you expecting to see the value of `PD` in there? Because it doesn't change the variables, it just creates a new environment that contains the `PD` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use `purrr` for this. Your function seems to look OK. Again, suppose you want to create a function that takes `a` and `b` as parameters and returns a function for evaluating `ax+b`. Here is what you do:

```
lin <- function(a,b){
  function(x) a*x + b
}
```

Then `lin(1,1)(1)` will give you `1*1 + 1 = 2`. `lin(1,0)(x)` will just give you the input value back for any `x`.